# Restrict query to last day with posts

Tags: query, date, frontpage

I am using the Delicacy theme. I want to show n my homepage the posts of the current day.
But if there are no post for that day it shows *"No found"*. I want to show posts from the last day with posts instead. How can I do that?

I am using this query:

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');
$current_day=date('d');

query_posts( 
    "cat=5&year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&day=$current_day&order=ASC" 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the most recent date with posts and use that to construct the `$current_` fields.

```
$last_date = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT DATE(MAX(post_date)) FROM {$wpdb->posts} LIMIT 1");
if (!empty($last_date)) {
    list($current_year,$current_month,$current_day) = explode('-',$last_date);
    query_posts( 
        "cat=5&year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&day=$current_day&order=ASC" 
    );
}
```